# Controlling ticks and odd text in a pie chart generated from a factor variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, pie-chart

I'm generating a simple pie chart with use of the code below:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$fac_var <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
require(ggplot2); require(ggthemes)

# Chart
pie_test <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(1), fill = fac_var)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  theme_pander() +
  scale_fill_tableau(name = "Something") +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

The code produces the following chart:

[image: first pie chart]

I'm interested in introducing two minor modifications to the chart above:

1. I would like to remove the figure *1* visible on the left *(highlighted in red in the picture below)*.
2. I would like to make the lines leading to to the figures more strongly pronounced *(highlighted in black in the picture below)*.

## Desired changes:

[image: Desired changes pie chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) To get rid of the "1-"
edit your theme to:

```
theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

2.) To change the lines edit your theme to:

```
theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
      axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 1, color="black", linetype = "solid"))
```

Not a perfect solution but an improvement.  Pie charts are not the best for conveying data.  You may want to consider a bar chart.  If you want more help with ggplot2 pie charts check out [this post](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-pie-chart-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization).

Comment: I agree concerning the general suitability of pie charts but in the context of the task at hand I'm specifically interested in generating a pie chart. Thanks for the answer.