# Add Leading Lines to ggplot2 Pie Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, data-visualization, pie-chart

I want to add leading lines to all the `slices` in my `ggplot` `Pie Chart`.

The second answer on this thread has them, but IDK what was added to reproduce the line, 
[ggplot pie chart labeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436214/ggplot-pie-chart-labeling?noredirect=1)

I've tried to copy and paste exactly what's in the line part of this answer, but I get some messed up lines: 
[Controlling ticks and odd text in a pie chart generated from a factor variable in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549739/controlling-ticks-and-odd-text-in-a-pie-chart-generated-from-a-factor-variable-i)

[image: Here's my messed up chart]

```r
lossmixchart <- ggplot(currentLoss, aes(x="", y = currentLoss$Incurred, fill = 
                Branch)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", colour = "black")+ 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = 
                c("British Columbia" = "royalblue3", "Alberta" = "red", 
                "Saskatchewan" = "green4", "Manitoba" = "gold", "Ontario" = 
                "turquoise", "New Brunswick"= "purple", "PEI" = "hotpink", 
                "Nova Scotia" = "orange")) +
  theme_void() + 
  ggtitle(paste0(
                "Incurred Loss Mix in Thousands ", 2019, ": " , currentProvince)
            ) + 
  geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(label = paste0(Branch, " \n $", 
                prettyNum(round(currentLoss$Incurred/1000), big.mark = ",")), x = 2), 
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), segment.size =.7, size = 5, 
                show.legend = FALSE) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 20), 
        axis.title = element_text(size=20),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())

 print(lossmixchart, floating = FALSE)
```

If I add `nudge_x = .3` after `size`, as some pages advise to try, I get this error:

> `` Error: Specify either `position` or `nudge_x`/`nudge_y ``

Comment: please add some example data, also please show, where exactly you add the `nudge_x`

Comment: I think you should add `nudge_x` to the `geom_text_repel` as in the answer you're referring to. There you're already setting a position which might cause the error

Comment: I already put it in geom_text_repel, after size like I said above, so it looks like this ```geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(label = paste0(Branch, " \n $", prettyNum(round(currentLoss$Incurred/1000), big.mark = ",")), x = 2), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), segment.size =.7, size = 5, nudge_x = .3,   show.legend = FALSE)```

Comment: I see several issues with your plotting calls. Please provide some example data to work on. What do you actually want to achieve with `nudge_x`? Move the labels more outward?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IxE0odVhLn41oU_-ECIOBdWiUXVDE_IvEn_MW2Lr5Mo/edit?usp=sharing

here's some data, Overall I want to add leading lines, however I also don't want my labels to overlap with the chart OR other labels, right now they do both sometimes

Comment: I have a loop right now that goes through the above data and filters based on each of the provinces for years (for this, all provinces is fine because I also have a chart that way) so at any given time, IDK how the labels for each loop will show up